# How to change theme template for the same block that is loaded twice on the page?

Tags: 8, theming, blocks, hooks, navigation

We have created two menu blocks: `main_menu (region=main nav)` and `main_menu_footer (region=footer)` that are added to all pages. They both are displaying the same `main navigation` menu except `main_menu_footer` only displays the first level and `main_menu` displays all levels.

I have a custom module, `mymodule` that I am using to assign a custom twig template, `menu--main.html.twig`. This twig template is being assigned to both blocks.

How can I setup the twig templates so that the `main_menu` uses `main--menu.html.twig` template, but `main_menu_footer` uses `main--menu--footer.html.twig`?

**Goal:**

1. `main_menu` block uses `main--menu.html.twig` template
2. `main_menu_footer` block uses `main--menu--footer.html.twig` template

**Current setup**

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $items = [];
  $items['main__menu'] = [
    'base hook' => 'menu',
    'render element' => 'menu',
  ];

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: You need to add theme name suggestions, but this can be tricky in this case to distinguish both menus, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193610/how-to-create-a-custom-twig-template-for-menu-block

Comment: One other thing, always start with the base hook when naming template hooks, so in this case `$items['menu__main']`.

Comment: @4k4 the link you shared helped me resolve my issue. i pasted the answer for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @4k4 suggestion, I got it resolved by doing the following

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_block().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  // Only proceed if id is valid. It is not valid for all blocks. 
  if(isset($variables['attributes']['id'])) {
    $variables['content']['#attributes']['block'] = $variables['attributes']['id'];
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function mymodule_theme_suggestions_menu_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  // Remove the block and replace dashes with underscores in the block ID to
  // use for the hook name.
  if (isset($variables['attributes']['block'])) {
    $hook = str_replace(array('block-', '-'), array('', '_'),    $variables['attributes']['block']);
    $suggestions[] = $variables['theme_hook_original'] . '__' . $hook;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done at the theme level, not the in a module. Unless you want to create your own implementation of a menu.
First of all, enable [Twig Debugging](https://www.drupal.org/node/1903374) then in locate in DOM the templates you want to override.
In your active theme, create a file with the same name as the twig template you want to override. Copy the code from the original template and customize it as you like

Comment: Yes, this is about the theming level, but you can use theming hooks in both, themes and modules.